# What considerations are required for making a hiking ascent of Mount Othrys, Greece

Tags: hiking

Despite searching the various online databases I cannot find any documented routes, reports of guides to ascending Mount Othrys / Gerakovouni.

Any help appreciated from people who have made the ascent or links to guides online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There you go: http://www.wikiloc.com/wikiloc/view.do?id=8287543.
In two languages, no less.

[image: three peaks of Othrys mountain walk]

> A long trek to three peaks of Othrys mountain (Gerakovouni 1640 m, Gkiouzi 1725 m, Piliouras 1558 m). Distance 17,1 km, walking time 6.45, total time 8,5 hours. Start and finish on the asphalt road, about 2,5 km apart. On Almiros main road exit towards Platanos, at the bridge turn right towards 'Kofoi'. Approaching Kofi village, turn left towards 'Tsatali'. Excellent views if the sky is clear, no shade except a short section in fir forest (so better avoid walking in summer period), no drinking water fountain on route.